# Endorsement fails when node.js fabric-client application is run on a separate node

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm running the [fabcar example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/fabcar) from fabric samples on a node. My fabric network is [first-network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/first-network) (BYFN) run inside docker containers and I would like to invoke chaincode using a node.js fabric-client application on a separate node (Raspberry Pi).

In [connection-org1.json](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/connection-org1.json) file, I have replaced the localhost domain names (in the peer urls) with my own domain name (mydomain.com) where the fabric network is running.

I execute [invoke.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/invoke.js) on Raspberry Pi with the following modified gateway settings:

```
await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false } });
```

This gives me an error message:

```
2019-07-04T07:15:30.124Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-07-04T07:15:30.132Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - endorsement failed - Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-07-04T07:15:30.134Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:9051
2019-07-04T07:15:30.135Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:1 - endorsement failed - Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:9051
Failed to submit transaction: Error: Endorsement has failed
```

I see that the domain names of the endorserers are the ones defined in the docker composer files, not the domain (mydomain.com) where my fabric network is running.

How should I configure the fabric network or the node.js fabric-client application so that I can invoke chaincode from my Raspberry Pi node?

Comment: It seems your peers are not accessible,means peers port are not open.

Comment: Have you tried discovery enabled: false ?

Comment: If I try discovery enabled: false, I get this error: 2019-07-08T07:58:41.600Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: no suitable peers available to initialize from                                                                                                  
Failed to submit transaction: Error: no suitable peers available to initialize from

Comment: I have all ports open at my host where I run the fabric network. This problem arises when I try to run fabric-client application from a separte host (Raspberry Pi).  Is there a way to configure the node.js fabric-client application manually?

Answer (score 3):

I made a workaround where I extended the `/etc/hosts` file on my Raspberry Pi. I made the endorsing peer domain names `peer0.org1.example.com` and `peer0.org2.example.com` to point to the IP address of my host where I run the fabric network (docker).

This fixed the issue and now I'm able to invoke chaincode from the Raspberry Pi host.