# No discovery results found and Endorsement has failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have modified the fabcar example to save my own data from an external API in the fabric version 1.4.4. Now I have upgraded the fabric to 2.2, and when I am trying to submit the transaction I am facing the error below.

```
 Error: No discovery results found
    at DiscoveryService.getDiscoveryResults (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:359:10)
    at DiscoveryHandler.endorse (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryHandler.js:156:40)
    at Endorsement.send (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/Proposal.js:341:29)
    at Transaction.submit (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:205:52)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
2020-07-30T12:48:56.927Z - error: [DiscoveryHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - error on endorsement to peer0.org2.example.com:9051 error Error: Broadcast Client peer0.org2.example.com:9051 grpcs://localhost:9051 is not connected
2020-07-30T12:48:56.927Z - error: [DiscoveryHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:1 - error on endorsement to peer0.org1.example.com:7051 error Error: Broadcast Client peer0.org1.example.com:7051 grpcs://localhost:7051 is not connected
error inside await { TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at newEndorsementError (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:33:39)
    at getResponsePayload (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:21:23)
    at Transaction.submit (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:207:28)
    at <anonymous>
  responses: [],
  errors: 
   [ { Error: Endorsement has failed
    at DiscoveryHandler._endorse (/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryHandler.js:237:18)
    at <anonymous> endorsements: [Array] } ] }
```

I have checked the running dockers in peer0 using **docker ps -a | grep peer0**

```
0f038564e3ff        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_1-393aaaa35016a08b9cb740a31ae2ea89aaf10d0bfdf65c817abfe904623681de-c46c7e2a1710c4aa83ac0326124e387b4a057046f3de852bad35bb44852aaec7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                 dev-peer0.org2.example.com-fabcar_1-393aaaa35016a08b9cb740a31ae2ea89aaf10d0bfdf65c817abfe904623681de
bf7a3565727c        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar_1-393aaaa35016a08b9cb740a31ae2ea89aaf10d0bfdf65c817abfe904623681de-fd6a5aa3b9b251ac2e8768f732744a944d9b52c15a7d40a1ed44d327aecaa399   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                 dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar_1-393aaaa35016a08b9cb740a31ae2ea89aaf10d0bfdf65c817abfe904623681de
748c5089c0c5        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                                                                                          "peer node start"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour    7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp             peer0.org2.example.com
2bf221d99453        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
```

Here is the connection profile for Org1

```
name: test-network-org1
version: 1.0.0
client:
  organization: Org1
  connection:
    timeout:
      peer:
        endorser: '300'
organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
    - peer0.org1.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
    - ca.org1.example.com
peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7051
    tlsCACerts:
      pem: |
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
         
          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
          
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      hostnameOverride: peer0.org1.example.com
certificateAuthorities:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    url: https://localhost:7054
    caName: ca-org1
    tlsCACerts:
      pem: 
        - |
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
       
          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
          
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
```

I have no idea why the first two containers are not listening to any ports. Also checked the logs of each containers, and did not found any errors too.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you please share the connection profile of your network and have checked the certificates?

Comment: Edited the question with connection profile

Comment: Refer to the link and see if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885082/endorsement-fails-when-node-js-fabric-client-application-is-run-on-a-separate-no

Comment: @KartikChauhan, I have tried it, Its not working